# Asymptotic form of the associated Legendre polynomials $P^m_l (z)$ at z=1

Tags: special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I want to find the asymptotic form of $P^m_l (z)$ at z=1.

The usual method is to simply plug the limit into the differential equation and then solve the reduced differential equation.

There's a $ \frac{m^2}{(1 - z^2)}$ term that diverges in this case though. Is it possible to find the form in some other way?

Comment: Do you want the results or a derivation? There are some expansions at
http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LegendreP2/06/01/02/

Comment: I just need the results. Thanks for the link.